# Most Efficient way to 'look up' Keywords

Tags: c++, search, performance, lexer

Alright so I am writing a function as part of a lexical analyzer that 'looks up' or searches for a match with a keyword. My lexer catches all the obvious tokens such as single and multi character operators (`+ - * / > < = == etc`) (also comments and whitespace are already taken out) so I call a function after I've collected a stream of only alphanumeric characters (including underscores) into a `string`, this string then needs to be matched as either a known keyword or an identifier.

So I was wondering how I might go about identifying it? I know I basically need to compare it to some list or array or something of all the built in keywords, and if it matches one return that match to it's corresponding enum value; otherwise, if there is no match, then it must be a function or variable identifier. So how should I look for matches? I read somewhere that something called a Binary Search Tree is an efficient way to do it or by using Hash Tables, problem is I've never used either so I am not sure if it's the right way. Could I possibly use a MySQL database?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479919/searching-fast-through-a-sorted-list-of-strings-in-c may help you

Comment: Using MySQL to do a keyword lookup in C++, would be like calling a Web Service to perform the addition of two integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your set of keywords is fixed, a [perfect hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash) can be built for O(1) lookup.  Check out [gperf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/gperf.html) or [cmph](http://cmph.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: You'd still have hash collisions with non-keywords, so I don't see this being more efficient than other methods.  It's also not O(1), true the complexity doesn't depend on the number of keywords but it does depend on the length of each keyword.

Comment: Verification after the lookup is a string compare, but this is unlikely to be an significant factor in the performance. Since the hash is perfect, there is no hash collision penalty, the input either matches the hashed slot or it doesn't, no additional search is needed.

Comment: Perfect hash functions are actually not that useful for compiler lexers; it's better to calculate a single hash and use it for both keyword lookup and symbol lookup in various per-scope hash tables. You can cheaply guarantee no collisions for keyword lookup by increasing the size of the keyword hashtable, or even better, add keywords to the globals hash table before adding anything else, so you need only one lookup to resolve both keywords and symbols. Or consider interning all idents (incl keywords) in a single global hash table for super-cheap pointer comparisons elsewhere in the compiler.

Comment: Keywords need to be found before globals or any other identifier, but otherwise I agree, that's probably what I would do before attempting any other optimizations based on perfect hashing.  I suspect it is rarely worth it.

Answer (score 2):

A ["trie"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) will surely be the most efficient way.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever implementation of [std::map](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html) you have will probably be sufficient.

Comment: Or `std::tr1::unordered_map` if your compiler supports it, which the latest VC++ and GCC both do. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is for a language, with a specific set of keywords that never change, and there aren't very many of them?

If so, it probably doesn't matter what you use. You will have bigger fish to fry.

However, since the list doesn't change, it would be hard to beat a hard coded search like this:

```
// search on first letter
switch(s[0]){
  case 'a':
    // search on 2nd letter, etc.
    break;
  case 'b':
    // search on 2nd letter, etc.
    break;
  ........
  case '_':
    // search on 2nd letter, etc.
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For singe character keywords a lookup table would be perfect. For multicharacter (especially if the lengths differs): a hash table. If you need performance, you could even use source code generation to create the hash tables (using a simple hash function that is able or not to ignore case, depending on your syntax).

So I'd implement it with a LUT and a hash table: first you check the first character with the LUT (if it's a simple operator, it would start with a non-alpha-numeric value), and, if not found, check the hash table.